# Connecting via oAuth2 with jQuery/AJAX for Box.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oauth-2.0, box-api

I'm trying to work with Box.com's API to develop a quick app that allows for Folder creation. I am having trouble connecting to their API and am fairly new to oAUTH2, API's, and whatnot. I've tried to follow these guides:

http://developers.box.com/oauth/

http://developers.box.com/docs/#folders-create-a-new-folder

The Box.com documentation says

> response_type: Whether the endpoint returns an authorization code. For
>   web applications, a value of code should be used.
>
> client_id : The client_id you obtained in the Initial Setup.
>
> redirect_uri :An HTTPS URI or custom URL scheme where the response
>   will be redirected. Optional if the redirect URI is registered with
>   Box already.
>
> state :    An arbitrary string of your choosing that will be
>   included in the response to your application. Box recommends that you
>   use an anti-forgery state token to prevent CSRF attacks to your users
>
> A sample GET request could therefore look like:
>
> GET
>   https: //www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&state=security_token%3DKnhMJatFipTAnM0nHlZA

I have a dev account with them and here is my basic jquery that is not working..

```
 $.ajax({
  //The URL to process the request
    url : 'https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize',
    type : 'GET',
    data : {
      response_type : 'code',
      client_id : 'm025a55gtov17txux1v2vbzjjhph2b6n'
    },
  success: function( resp ) {
    console.log( resp.people );
  },
  error: function( req, status, err ) {
    console.log( 'something went wrong', status, err );}

  });
```

Can anyone point me in the direction on how to do this? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a way to connect to their API and get a token, but now I am getting a CORS error when I try and send a POST request to their server to create a folder (the main goal of my app) for anyone interested.. here is how I trade off the code for the token

```
authorizeUser = function(){    

        var results = $.ajax({

            // The URL to process the request
            url : 'https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token',
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
                grant_type : 'authorization_code',
                code : data.boxAuthorizationCode,
                client_id : data.clientId,
                client_secret : data.clientSecret
            },
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
               //console.log(response);
               console.log(response.access_token);
               data.access_token = response.access_token;
               tokenGranted();
            }

        });

        return results.responseText;

    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Axios instead of ajax

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qs/6.9.4/qs.js"></script>
```

After requiring this script you can write your own javascript function and it will work.

clientId: Pass dynamic client id.
secret: Pass dynamic secret.

```
      async  function runAuthQuery(params) {
          const config = {
          url: '{WebURL}',
          method: 'post',
          data: Qs.stringify({
            grant_type: 'client_credentials',
            client_id: clientId,
            client_secret: secret,
          })
        };
        const bearerToken = await axios(config);
        const getPlayableUrl = await axios.get(`{WebURL}`,
          {
            "headers": {
              "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
              "authorization": `Bearer ${bearerToken.data.access_token}`
            }
          });
        }
```

It is working fine for me.