# Requesting OAuth2 Token With AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to use AJAX to request a token. This will only be used on localhost to make the request. I've got the code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "TOKEN URL HERE",
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("grant_type", "client_credentials");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("client_id", "ENTER CLIENT ID");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("client_secret", "ENTER CLIENT SECRET");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  },
  dataType: "json",
  //content-Type: "application/json",
  type: "POST",
  success: function(response) {
    token = response.access_token;
    expiresIn = response.expires_in;
  },
  error: function(errorThrown) {
    alert(errorThrown.error);
  }
});
```

However, it doesn't work. Is this the correct approach or have I got the parameters incorrect? (Or is OAuth2 token request just not possible with AJAX/JQuery/JS)

Comment: Please check this if its works for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/62317987/7225569

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Piotr P wasn't working for me. The client I am getting the tokens from did not accept the client id and credentials when send as part of the data. I had to use basic authentication instead. This is the ajax call that worked for me.

```
$.ajax({
  "type": "POST",
  "url": "https://some.domain.com/oath/token",
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)
  },

  "data": {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
  },


  "success": function(response) {
    token = response.access_token;
    expiresIn = response.expires_in;
  },
  "error": function(errorThrown) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(errorThrown.error()));
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Are sure, that grant_type, client_id, client_secret should be passed by headers instead of payload?

Try to remove them from headers (left accept, content-type only), and then add "data" property with rest of params.

Something like that:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "TOKEN URL HERE",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    },
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        client_id: "ENTER CLIENT ID",
        client_secret: "ENTER CLIENT SECRET",
        grant_type: "client_credentials"
    },
    type: "POST",
    success: function(response) {
        token = response.access_token;
        expiresIn = response.expires_in;
    },
    error: function(errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown.error);
    }
});
```