# Strava API authorization

Tags: javascript, strava

I am able to initiate the GET https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize link.  Now I can get the code in the returned url parameters.  So now i want to be able to retrieve the code from the URL params, but don't know what initial event on the returned URL from strava to retrieve and set the local storage.  I have managed to do it in a button click function, but don't want users to use more that one button click to retrieve the data. Any help would be great!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button1").click(function(){
window.location.href ="http://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXXX&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:5500&approval_prompt=force&scope=read_all,profile:read_all,activity:read_all"
  }); 
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button2").click(function() {  //need help here
 var Qstring = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
 var code = Qstring.get('code');
 var state = Qstring.get('state');
 localStorage.setItem("code", code);
 console.log(code);
 console.log(localStorage.getItem("code"))   
 document.getElementById("demo").innerText = code
  });
});
```

Comment: If you're following a guide from strava, please include that in your question. Does strava specify that you have to redirect in order to get the token? There are [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62317987/8950658) of how you can use Oauth asynchronously using $.ajax or axios

Comment: I don't know well jQuery but maybe is possible use URLSearchParams on document load without a button click event.